# Unable to reference Logic App Action output in inline Javascript

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to access an action output in Logic App inline Javascript action as follows:
[image]

However, this leads to an error while saving the workflow -

Failed to save logic app <>. The template validation failed: 'The action(s) '@outputs('Get_current_loop_object')' referenced by 'inputs' in action 'Wrap_Work_Relationship_data_to_array_if_needed' are not defined in the template.'.

Any ideas what I may be missing?

Comment: seems I have run into this limitation described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code
"This capability doesn't support variables, loops, and iteration indexes.";
which should be rephrased as -
"...,actions within loops,..."

Answer (score 0):

As per my repro It works for me by using following steps with inline java script :

Click on the **Workflow settings** menu bar.

[image]

After that select **integration** account which you created:-

[image]

Add files in get content:

[image]

Then Initialize the variable  name with object type which is needed.(variable "json" should have to be initialized & declared before using it in the java script)
[image]

Coming to Action item part you need to mention the function or the operation as action item that you have mentioned in the below javascript connector in the logic app.

[image]

Saved it successfully:

[image]

NOTE:- It is not supported with loop as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code#include-action-results)

For further details refer this [link](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip227.html) .